# Approximate/Find Function

Tags: functions, regression

I have got values $x_{i}$ and targets $z_{i}$.
Now I want to find a function $f(x)=z$, which approximates the mapping of my value $x_{i}$ to its targetvalue $z_{i}$ as good as possible for every $x_{i}$.
I do not no any connection or physical background of these values. I hope at least there is something like a correlation between them.

Can anybody help me (eg with a catchword to google, hint)?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html

Comment: Why you don´t have any connection between the values ? What kind of data do you have ?

Comment: Relevant (duplicate?) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195471/given-a-collection-of-consecutive-points-can-i-find-a-graph-equation-that-goes/1195473#1195473

Comment: How many values ?

Comment: Kernel Regression

Comment: @calculus: Coefficients of optimal values for a NP-hard Optimization Problem against some characterizing values of the problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: About 2000 Values.

Comment: @MatrixMan: check my answer. A single polynomial interpolator is out of question.

Answer (score 1):

There are many interpolation and approximation methods available, depending on your requirements (in terms of smoothness, robustness to noise, computational cost...). Most of them are base on polynomials or piecewise polynomial functions.

Interpolation makes sure that $f(x_i)=z_i$, while approximation realizes $f(x_i)\approx z_i$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_analysis_topics#Polynomial_interpolation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_analysis_topics#Spline_interpolation

Without knowing anything of your case, I would consider [cubic spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation#Algorithm_to_find_the_interpolating_cubic_spline).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague. There exists an infinite number of functions that fit the requirements you listed so far.

For example, one such function is:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}z_1; & x=x_1\\ z_2; & x=x_2\\ \vdots\\ z_n; & x=x_n\\ 0; &\text{else} \end{cases}$$

This function perfectly maps all values $x_i$ to ther targets. It is probably **not** the function you are looking for. You need more restrictions before you can hope to get a good answer to your question.

---

You may think that requiring a continuous function would be enough, but it is not. There are still infinitely many functions that satisfy your conditions. One of them is defined as $$f(x) = z_i + \frac{(x-x_i}{x_{i+1}-x_i} (z_{i+1}-z_i)$$ on the interval $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$ (assuming $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n$), but it is far from the only one.

---

You may want **analytic** functions, but even **THAT** is not enough. There exists infinitely many polynomials $p$ that satisfy the requirement $\forall i: p(x_i) = z_i$.

And not only polynomials, for any collection $\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_n$ for which no two $\lambda_i$ are equal, you can find a set of constants $A_1,\dots A_n$ such that $f(x) = A_1e^{\lambda_1 x}+\cdots+A_ne^{\lambda_n}$ will satisfy the requirement $\forall i: f(x_i)=z_i$.

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for the analytic representation.

Comment: @MatrixMan See the edit to my answer. You still need more rigorous demands.